# Missing type definition for IDBObjectStore.getAll()?

Tags: typescript, indexeddb

[`IDBObjectStore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBObjectStore) has a method [`getAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBObjectStore/getAll).

However, TypeScript reports no such method. The relevant section in `lib.d.ts` is:

```
interface IDBObjectStore {
    readonly indexNames: DOMStringList;
    keyPath: string | string[];
    readonly name: string;
    readonly transaction: IDBTransaction;
    autoIncrement: boolean;
    add(value: any, key?: IDBKeyRange | IDBValidKey): IDBRequest;
    clear(): IDBRequest;
    count(key?: IDBKeyRange | IDBValidKey): IDBRequest;
    createIndex(name: string, keyPath: string | string[], optionalParameters?: IDBIndexParameters): IDBIndex;
    delete(key: IDBKeyRange | IDBValidKey): IDBRequest;
    deleteIndex(indexName: string): void;
    get(key: any): IDBRequest;
    index(name: string): IDBIndex;
    openCursor(range?: IDBKeyRange | IDBValidKey, direction?: string): IDBRequest;
    put(value: any, key?: IDBKeyRange | IDBValidKey): IDBRequest;
}
```

with no `getAll()` in sight. Is this a bug in the type definitions?

Using TS 2.2.1, with target es6.

Comment: Probably. These type definitions are [generated](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14322#issuecomment-282819512) by some [tool](https://github.com/Microsoft/TSJS-lib-generator) that in turn uses XML spec file generated by the Microsoft Edge browser, which [does not seem to have it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465965.aspx).

Comment: More specifically, getAll is from the IndexedDB 2.0 spec, and Edge currently has only partial support for the 1.0 spec. On the plus side, I wrote a polyfill https://github.com/dumbmatter/IndexedDB-getAll-shim

Comment: Why would it be generated based on Edge and not on the actual ES6 standards?

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can create a type definitions file like `indexeddb.d.ts` into your project with the following content:

```
interface IDBObjectStore {
    getAll(): IDBRequest;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it' a bug in typescript, and it's already fixed
Try to use newer version of it

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24724